# SSIS Insert continuous data from one server / database to another

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, data-transfer

I have 2 different Servers (Server1 and Server2). On each is a database (db1 and db2) with a similar structure.
There are continuous data inserts in db1.

I want a job extracting the data from one server (db1) to the other server (db2) on a daily schedule using SSIS and SQL Server agent for the scheduler.
I only want transfer the new Data (the data which is not transferred in an earlier job) to the db2.

For this I want to select the last Id from db2 and use it to transfer only the data from db1 which have a higher id.

The concept itself works, but I don't know how to implement it with SSIS.

In SSIS I tried to use SQL execution tasks and safe it into variables:

First task (to safe the id in a variable):
`SELECT TOP (1) [ID] FROM [DB2] ORDER BY ID DESC`

Second task (safe the rows into object variable):
`SELECT * FROM [DB1] where ID > ?`

That works, but how can I insert the object variable into the db2.

Isn't there a cleaner way like:

```
Insert into Server2.[db2] select * from Server1.[db1] where ID > ?
```

The problem is, that SSIS only allows **one** connection for each SQL execution (same problem with dataflow tasks).

I also thought about temporary tables. But I'm not sure if this is the right way.

Would be awesome if someone got an idea / hint. I have not found much about this and I guess its an simple task.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: One way to tackle this is created Server2 as a Linked Server on Server1 - this allows you to query db2 from a connection to Server1.

Comment: Also, have you considered [Log shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) as an alternative to hand-crafting your database synchronisation?

Comment: Ty for the idea. I guess i missed writing some important information: its one on premise server and one Azure managed instance. If im right its not possible to log shipping informations with this circumstances: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232332/is-it-possible-to-log-ship-from-on-premise-sql-server-to-azure-sql-managed-insta

Comment: Sry for not beeing clear enough. But one reason why i wanted to use SSIS is to avoid linked server. But it was a good idea. Ty

Comment: Assume this is write-only data? Otherwise, aren't you missing the changed/deleted records?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most of the way there.  Just use a dataflow task instead of an execute SQL task.  A data flow can have two different connections.

1. Get the last id and put it in a variable with an ExecuteSQL Task.  Then connect a data flow task

[image]

2. Configure the data flow task with a source and destination

[image]

3. In this example, we are using an OLEDB Source with a SQL command which accepts a parameter using "?"

[image]

4. We click on the parameter button and select the variable that we want to map to it

[image]

5. Finally, map the fields in the destination to the second server by clicking on the destination, selecting the server connection manager and table, and click on the mappings tab